# Is it possible to move A layout towards left so that other side of screen can be visible?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-motionlayout

Actually, I am trying to build a game in which the scene is outside the screen.
I want my screen to scroll towards the right so that my that scene comes to the screen when I click any button.
I am doing it using **motionLayout** in Android studio.
Can any one help?

Comment: try it with horizontal scrollview

Comment: yes i tried but didnt find it useful.

Comment: i think i wad doing it wrong..can you please demonstrate?

Comment: for now post your code snippet how are you doing what is the current state and how you want it to be so that others also can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I motionLayout you would constrain the view fully on screen in one state and fully off screen in the other. Than the transition would "slide" the view in.

The typical problem when people do this with MotionLayout is how to constrain a "full size view" outside the bounds of the screen.

There are several ways to accomplish this 2 are:

1. used layout_width="match_parent"  & layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
2. use layout_width="0dp" & layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent" andlayout_constraintWidth_percent="1"

The key is you are constraining the left side of the view to the right side of the parent.

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples#multi-state) is an example of layout the constraints for slide in.